# Pairing and bonding with BLE on Android 5.1

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I implemented the BLE example shown [here](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1553/bluetooth_smart_le_android_tutorial) on my Android 2013 Nexus 7 with Android 5.1.

Essentially, a list of all BLE devices (peripherals) that are advertising are listed. When the user clicks one item in the list, a new intent is started and the selected peripheral is connected to. This is working fine. Now I modified my BLE peripheral to use pairing/bonding. Once it bonds to the central, the central is added to a white list and the peripheral then uses advertises only to the white list for 30 seconds, and then does general advertising for another 30 seconds (if nothing connected during the white list advertising). The peripheral then sleeps if no connection occurs during the general advertising. When it is awoken the process repeats.

How do I modify the code such that once the peripheral is bonded to, then next time the app scans and the peripheral is white list advertising, the app automatically connects to this peripheral? Another feature of the app will be that it can also send a command to clear the peripherals white list. If this command is issued, then the app should also clear itself from attempting to bond with this peripheral until the bond is recreated (i.e., the general advertising list of peripherals should be made again, and if this bondable peripheral is chosen again, a bond should be created and reconnected to automatically in the future).

The peripheral is implemented using a TI CC2640 using the white list and bonding APIs as shown in the cycling sensor example, if that helps clarify things. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am looking at a similar issue now.